# Install ftp Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to enable the ftp in ubuntu. I write in the terminal the command setup-ftp but the answer is "setup-ftp: command not found". Where am I wrong?

Comment: What FTP? There are many. Why would `setup-ftp` work? Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do. Do you want to connect to an FTP server? Do you want to allow others to connect to your machine through FTP?

Comment: ftp client or ftp server ?

Comment: I'm trying to follow this tutorial about linux:
http://postimg.org/image/5mktc8lxl/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so there is no such program as `setup-ftp` for Ubuntu. I think you would mean to get `vsftpd` which can help you set up FTP and SFTP servers. So with that being said, the proper command to install is:

`sudo apt-get install vsftpd`

If you are looking for a client to connect to FTP/SFTP servers, you will need a program such as FileZilla to do so:

`sudo apt-get install filezilla`